# Algorithm Visualization tool for C?

Tags: c

Are there existing algorithm visualization tool for C programs? like visualizing an execution of a C program through animated execution stack.

Comment: kind of debugger but with animation

Comment: funny silico, but I'm not referring to a static animation.

Comment: Some debuggers colour code or flash the fields that were changed by the last step/next/run-to-cursor operation, and some even have a undo / redo capability - likely OS/CPU specific (which you haven't specified).  If you expect something like a powerpoint presentation, then I've never heard of anything - the potential memory/register changes tend to be too numerous and complicated to automatically summarise in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) for fancy GUI debugging visualizations. It visualizes all the data structures and makes pretty graphs and gives you access to your regular debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Studio for Linux (former Sun Studio) Performance Analyzer has the timeline feature.
That is exactly an animated stack representation.

Like on this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For C++, there are educational program visualizers that you might want to try:

- [VIP](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~vip/en/) (Visual InterPreter), you should be able to visualize your own code by editing one of the examples on the site. Supports only a C++ subset, though.
- [The Teaching Machine](http://www.theteachingmachine.org/), can be used as a Java program or an Eclipse plugin.

EDIT: Updated the The Teaching Machine link.

Comment: The Teaching Machine is a dead link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ollydbg with the [ollyflow](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/OllyFlow_%28+_OllyGraph%29) plugin, or have a look at IDA
 with its [call graphing plugin](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=99) (there are other plugins along these lines as well).

Answer (score 0):

[C Tutor - Visualize C code execution to learn C online](http://www.pythontutor.com/c.html)

Is a great tool for visualizing the workflow of your C/C++ code - as well as a number of other languages.  To my knowledge you cannot enter any command line arguments, but that's the only limitation I can think of.  The benefits are that it is free, web based, and very intuitive.